# How to remove %20 from url with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to remove %20,:,/,? and many more from url with .htaccess?
im already try code from this post, but still not replace/redirect to new url
[.htaccess url rewrite and removing %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288118/htaccess-url-rewrite-and-removing-20).

this my .htaccess code

```
    RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (remove query string)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+content\.php\?judul=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L,NE]

# convert all space (%20) to hyphen
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [N,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

# rewrite rule to call actual PHP handler
RewriteRule ^([^./]+)\.html$ content.php?judul=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

my link
http://localhost/web/content.php?judul=Fate/Apocrypha
http://localhost/web/content.php?judul=Isekai%20wa%20Smartphone%20to%20Tomo%20ni

i want "%20" and "/" replace with "-" like this one.
http://localhost/web/content.php?judul=Fate-Apocrypha/
http://localhost/web/content.php?judul=Isekai-wa-Smartphone-to-Tomo-ni/

Comment: From here it looks like you're trying to address the input from the browser and not the output from your web application, `%20` is a url encoded space character, don't put spaces in URL notations and they won't encode that way.

Comment: that link automatic generate from `<a href="content.php?judul=<?php echo $value['judul']; ?></a>`

Comment: you can use the php space remove function like this
     <a href="content.php?judul=<?php echo str_replace(' ','-',$value['judul']); ?>" > </a>

Comment: then how to rewrite in htaccess, i can replace it with -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add these 2 rules before your last rewrite rule:

```
# replace %20 and / in QUERY_STRING by hyphen
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?(?:/|%20)+.*)$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^/]*?)(?:/|%20)+([^/]+?)/?$"
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1-%2/ [L,R=302,NE]
```

Comment: u can check my web here http://stanime.pe.hu/ im tested upload it..
u can see the url by u self, hope u can help me :D

im using urldecode and urlencode my .htaccess https://github.com/jazuly/ahp/blob/master/.htaccess since no one work, im delete all

Comment: yeah cause im using urlencode and decode space will replace with "+", but some character like "/" and ":" that convert with %2xx... can i replace it with "-" or "+"?

Comment: then how i can rewrite `http://stanime.pe.hu/content.php?link=Katsugeki%2FTouken+Ranbu` to `http://stanime.pe.hu/Katsugeki%2FTouken+Ranbu`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44758614/how-to-rewriterule-url-using-htaccess

Comment: Hmm interesting to see a downvote on a working and accepted answer without any comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code , hope it will help you.

```
# remove spaces from start or after /
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)[\s%20]+(.+)$ $1$2 [L]

# remove spaces from end or before /
RewriteRule ^(.+?)[\s%20]+(/.*|)$ $1$2 [L]

# replace spaces by - in between
RewriteRule ^([^\s%20]*)(?:\s|%20)+(.*)$ $1-$2 [L,R]
```

NOte- Must add that you need to fix the source of these URLs also because it is really not normal to be getting URLs like this.

Comment: stil getting %20 in my url

Comment: did you enable rewrite module in htaccess, RewriteEngine On

Comment: i try this one work, but displaying not found, content not displaying,
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^%20]*)%20([^\s]*) [NC]
`<br>`RewriteRule ^ /%1-%2 [L,NE,R]`

Comment: yeah, im already AllowOverride All & uncomment mod_rewrite.so from httpd.conf

Comment: try anathor method- replace space before send parameter to url. $yourstring="Isekai-wa-Smartphone-to-Tomo-ni";

$params=str_replace(' ', '-', $yourstring);

?judul=$params

Comment: im just using default url, how to costumize url?

Comment: how to rewrite in htaccess?