# How to rewriterule URL using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how to rewriterule for link like this

```
http://stanime.pe.hu/content.php?idf=15&link=Katsugeki--Touken+Ranbu
```

to `http://stanime.pe.hu/15/Katsugeki--Touken+Ranbu`

im encode and decode my url using Urlencode and urldecode

in database Collation im using latin1_swedish_ci

so, `space` will replace with `+` and `/` replace with `%2f` and more...

this my .htacces code

```
    RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+content\.php\?link=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ content.php?link=$1 [B,L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to add this directive in your vhost or `http.conf` file:

```
AllowEncodedSlashes On
```

This will allow encoded slash character i.e. `%2F` in URLs.

You can use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+content\.php\?idf=([^\s&]+)&link=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/(.+)$ content.php?idf=$1&link=$2 [B,L,QSA]
```

Comment: since im using free hosting i cant access apache file. is there another way?

Comment: Unfortunately `AllowEncodedSlashes` is only allowed in Apache config.

Comment: haha, sad to hear that... im try looking for httpd.conf in my dedicated, but i cant find in /etc/apache2, no file with name httpd.conf

Comment: i find an error when i have same title, then i modif my link to be like this?
`http://stanime.pe.hu/content.php?idf=15&link=Katsugeki--Touken+Ranbu` i want link will be like this `http://stanime.pe.hu//15/Katsugeki--Touken+Ranbu`

Comment: Ah but that's a different URL since you have 2 query parameters now.

Comment: yeah. hahaha, when im posting new with same title i got error. lol..
so im add id...

can u edit u answer?

Comment: I will edit once but once again I have to tell you that adding new requirements from comments is not good.

Comment: `+` from url direct to `%2b` code before not direct my `+`
u can try it

Answer (score 0):

you have to add character rules like below. Because your data is in character form not only number in url that you have defined here.

```
  RewriteRule    ^content/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$    content.php?link=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: still objeck not found `http://localhost/web/content/Fate%2FApocrypha` `RewriteRule ^content/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$ content.php?link=$1 [NC,L]`

Comment: if you have to check this url then what happened?
  http://localhost/web/content/Fate-Apocrypha

Comment: just working for url without space or special character..
when i try open http://stanime.pe.hu/content/Katsugeki%2FTouken+Ranbu

error displaying, u can try by urself  http://stanime.pe.hu/

Comment: okay why are you add space in url? you can remove the space before the making url at your link. For this you can use the str_replace funtion

Comment: hahaha, im using native php for create my web, im not realy understand how to route the right URL, url generate based the title