# Remove %20 Spaces from URL and product.php?name=$1

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

Would appreciate some assistance removing spaces from my URLs; and the CMS generates a php extension to I'd like help removed. 
Can not change these in the CMS, things are to dynamic. So I think it has to be htaccess.

I tried this: [How to remove %20 from url with .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733073/how-to-remove-20-from-url-with-htaccess)
Which worked to remove spaces, but it did not redirect my content.

I also got this to remove product.php?name=$

```
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product.php?name=$1 [L]
```

But that won't redirect anything.

They don't work together.

Currently have this at the top of my htaccess:

```
     <IfModule mod_expires.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteBase /
```

So Basically:

```
     www.randomsite.com/product.php?name=One%20Two%20Three
     needs to be:
     www.randomsite.com/One-Two-Three 
     or even...
     www.randomsite.com/One-Two-Three/
```

And hopefully handle redirects, or maybe I need to write redirects after all this. Idk.
Thank you!

Comment: Your <IfModule mod_expires.c> is wrong - it should be <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Comment: See first: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Comment: Redirect loops are the wrong way to fix this. Crafting the rewriterules to swap hyphens and encoded spaces is quite tedious.