# Decoding a URL on Redirect with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect from inside my Apache Server to an external google doc but can't seem to decode the URL, so any assistance would be great.

I have following code

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)com(.*)
RewriteRule ^redirect(.*) https://external.example.com/%2 [R=302,QSD]
```

I am using this code to redirect the following URL

```
http://my.example.com/redirect?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fforms%2Fd%2Fe%2F*SomeGoogleStuffHere*%2Fviewform
```

To this URL (Which is what it does and is so very close to what I need)

```
https://my.example.com/%252Fforms%252Fd%252Fe%252F*SomeGoogleStuffHere*%252Fviewform
```

The encoding from the second URL is causing me problems. For testing purposes, I removed the encoding myself via the browser address bar and replace it with '/'. This works so I know I am on the right track.

But as that is not an acceptable solution, I am left with:

> Error 404 - Page Not Found

When trying to reach

> https://docs.google.com/my_redirected_url

I have tried multiple things to no avail which can be seen below

My .htaccess file below

```
RewriteEngine on # Turn on RewriteEngine
//EXPECTED == > Replace all "%2F" WITH '/'
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^%2F]*?)(?:%2F)+([^%2F]+?(?:%2F)+.*)$"
#RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [N,NE]

//EXPECTED == > Replace all "%2F" WITH '/'
#RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^%2F]*?)(?:%2F)+([^%2F]+?)/?$"
#RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2/ [L,R=302,NE]

//EXPECTED == > Replace all "%2F" WITH '/'
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} "^([^%2F]*?)(?:%2F)+([^%2F]+?(?:%2F)+.*)$"
RewriteRule %{REQUEST_URI}?%1/%2 [N,NE]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)com(.*)$
RewriteRule ^redirect(.*) https://docs.google.com/%2 [r=301,QSD]
```

[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44733073/how-to-remove-20-from-url-with-htaccess) was helpful but seems like it catered to PHP.

I have only been using mod_rewrite for about a week or so and I feel like there is something simple I am missing but can't put my finger on it.

Comment: You need to turn on `encoded slashes` in your server configuration in order to use `℅2F` in url . https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowencodedslashes

Comment: See the [accepted](https://serverfault.com/questions/925925/redirect-to-encoded-url-parameter-using-mod-rewrite-in-htaccess) answer on the similar question. I would recommend too using own script (php/python/nodejs ...) for this task.

Comment: @Jigius Thanks for replying. the app itself is made with Invision app so It's all auto generated code and served using Apache which is hosted on GCP. I was possibly thinking to move the app to Node with Express to handle redirects etc then serve the Node app from Apache but that seems like overkill to me

Comment: @starkeen I turned that on but the problem is the double encoding, for some reason it completely ignores the Encoded Slashes both from my server config file and my virtualhost config file

Comment: Cross-site post on ServerFault, with accepted solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/955304/decoding-a-rewritten-url-using-mod-rewrite-htaccess-regex