# URL double encoding issue html +Apache2.2 +Mod_rewrite

Tags: html, apache, mod-rewrite

Looks like double encoded url changes the content inside the html file.

RewriteRule ^/about/test.html(.*)$  /test/test.html$1 [NE]

rule works fine, but for double encoded it adds %20 in html file

Eg. 
Title
Test%20Test%20Test%20

is there a way to clean the html file us mod_rewrite or this issue is not related to Apache+redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got answer from [.htaccess url rewrite and removing %20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25288118/htaccess-url-rewrite-and-removing-20)

this rule may affect all , instead use %{REQUEST_URI} apply for required uri.